# How to layout textview to make it be center in the 1/4 position of the parent linearLayout?

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-linearlayout

To be clear, if the parent linearLayout is 480dp, I need my textview be centered in 80 dp position, if the textview is 10 dp width, then it takes 75dp to 85 dp as its space, How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the **layout weight** property for the object, I believe. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="whatever" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In this example, the **View** object is being used to fill the empty space with something and enforce the 1/4 weight of the **TextView** object. I am a little rusty on my Android programming, so I hope this works for you.

Comment: No, this will not work, I mean the textview should be centered in the 80 dp position, that means it may take 75 to 85 as its space.

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake. I will leave this here for now so other people do not give the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `TextView` half the width of the parent using `layout_weight`, then center the text with `android:gravity`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```